# More than 256 colors for xp .ico

Tags: windows-xp, icons, c#

I am working in a windows form application with .net 4.0 c#. I am having a problem with the .ico images. The machines that will use de application have xp installed(some of them). I've been having problems trying to use the application because of the icons(more than 256 color for .ico format). The computers are old and installing them Windows 7 wouldn't be a good solution. Do you know any way to make xp accepts more than 256 colors in .ico files.?

Comment: Nope. You're probably going to have to break down and create 256-color versions of your icons.

Comment: Why are colors a trouble in XP? The size matters, and the 256x256 size is not supported in XP, but actually full 32-bit colors.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP supports icons with more than 256 colors. MSDN Developer Network : [Creating Windows XP Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx)

The sizes/colors and where they are used (note 16m colors is 32bits total, 24bit color and 8bit alpha channel):

Image sizes:

```
16x16: taskbar, windows upper-left corner, detailed lists.
24x24: Windows XP start menu.
32x32: desktop, by Windows Explorer.
48x48: Windows XP Explorer and system lists.
```

Color depths:

```
Monochrome: Not used.
16 colors: the screen is 16 or 256 colors.
256 colors: the screen is 64K or 16M colors.
16M colors (XP): Displayed by Windows XP if screen is 16M or more.
```

If an image format is missing, Windows displays the nearest existing image. It works but quality suffers.